# How to Create Live Wallpaper container?

Tags: android, live-wallpaper, launch

I am creating an launcher application where I want to functionality to set Live wallpaper, any one have idea how to create container for live wallpaper.

let me know if any suggestion/idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you want to accomplish, but If you want to set a live wallpaper from your own application you will still have to make the appropriate calls into android. I am not aware of a way to actually set it yourself and bypass the managers. I'm certain that you will still have to extend WallpaperService and also Engine to make a Live Wallpaper.

Comment: do u have any idea about issue mention here
http://stackoverflow.com/q/13700683/336990